# Data Truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9F…'

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, twitter, utf-8

I am doing a project on twitter feeds, for that i am using Mysql and java. To support multiple languages i made database collation utf8mb4 as well as the tables and their columns i-e utf8mb4_general_ci.

This is the connection string of mysql

```
host="jdbc:mysql://localhost/tweets?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
```

i also add meta tag on jsp page where i am getting these tweets

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

after all these changes i still getting this error

```
Data Truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9F…'
```

Please tell where am i doing wrong

Comment: First thing to do: work out where the problem is. Separate the JSP part from the MySql part. It sounds like you would probably see the same problem just using a console app - so do that. Apart from anything else, it'll make it *much* simpler to debug.

Comment: Next, find out what's putting the data *into* the database - you haven't told us anything about that.